# How to get value of this HTML on WebBrowser and Put to Textbox?

Tags: vb.net, button, textbox, webbrowser-control

By pressing the button, I would like to get the **value="your@mail.com"** from that HTML snippet and put it inside the textbox. Any idea to do this?

```
<input id="mail" onclick="select(this);" data-original-title="Your temporary Email address" class="mail opentip" value="your@mail.com" data-placement="bottom" title="" type="text" readonly="">
```

I'm trying this code but don't work.

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("value").InvokeMember("click")
TxtBox_Email.Text = Clipboard.GetText()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`GetAttribute()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the value of the [**`value` attribute**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp) *(hah!)*. The attribute holds the value of whatever's written in an `input` element.

By the way, [**`GetElementById()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx) expects the ***id*** of the element, which in this case is ***"mail"***, not "value".

```
Dim MailElement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mail")

If MailElement IsNot Nothing Then 'Necessary check: Was the element found?
    TxtBox_Email.Text = MailElement.GetAttribute("value")
End If
```

Comment: @SérgioWilker : Glad I could help! Good luck!